# What is the standard/best-practice/convenient way to call another Lambda in IronFunctions?

Tags: lambda, architecture, ironfunctions

What is the standard/best-practice/convenient way to call another Lambda in IronFunctions?

As I can understand, the answer maybe an HTTP request to localhost as external call. But this way does not cover situations with clustering (Swarm for example) due to different hosts and load balancing.

Maybe there is some library (high-level wrapper) for this?

Answer (score 0):

in case of cluster like swarm also we can use HTTP as the replicas are created and called as part of Service we Can call the function with the help of Service Name or IP